# Job fail with allowed memory size at Laravel 6 through Horizon

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-horizon

Running a job, through a loop after 3000 registers I receive:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   16384 bytes) {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 1):
>   Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
>   16384 bytes) at
>   /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php:117)

My job has: `public $timeout = 950;`

I'm using Laradock environment with php 7.2, Laravel 6, Horizon, Redis, MySql.

My setting horizon.php has:

```
 'memory_limit' => 2048,
 'environments' => [
        'local' => [
            'supervisor-1' => [
                'connection' => 'redis',
                'queue' => ['journey_processing','default','journey_calculations'],
                'balance' => 'false',
                'minProcesses' => 1,
                'maxProcesses' => 1,
                'tries' => 1,
                'delay' => 0,
                'sleep' => 3,
                'timeout' => 420 // Timeout after 7 minutes
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

My queue redis settings:

```
'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 2990,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],
```

My php info about memory:

[image: My PHP Info]

My docker environment memory.
[image: My docker desktop]

Comment: If I was asking this question I'd be posting as much as I possibly could about the most important piece of your problem: __the job itself__.

Comment: laravel 6  have problem now , it is not stable and return to develop

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I remember that I installed a Telescope and after that, the problem with memory in job starts. So I was checking job log, and saw this:

```
[2019-09-19 09:55:12][3449] Processing: App\Jobs\CreateJourney

   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException  : Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)

  at /var/www/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Storage/DatabaseEntriesRepository.php:145
    141|         $table = $this->table('telescope_entries');
    142| 
    143|         $entries->chunk($this->chunkSize)->each(function ($chunked) use ($table) {
    144|             $table->insert($chunked->map(function ($entry) {
  > 145|                 $entry->content = json_encode($entry->content);
    146| 
    147|                 return $entry->toArray();
    148|             })->toArray());
    149|         });


   Whoops\Exception\ErrorException  : Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)

  at /var/www/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Storage/DatabaseEntriesRepository.php:145
    141|         $table = $this->table('telescope_entries');
    142| 
    143|         $entries->chunk($this->chunkSize)->each(function ($chunked) use ($table) {
    144|             $table->insert($chunked->map(function ($entry) {
  > 145|                 $entry->content = json_encode($entry->content);
    146| 
    147|                 return $entry->toArray();
    148|             })->toArray());
    149|         });

  Exception trace:

  1   Whoops\Run::handleError("Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)", "/var/www/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Storage/DatabaseEntriesRepository.php")
      /var/www/vendor/filp/whoops/src/Whoops/Run.php:433

  2   Whoops\Run::handleShutdown()
```

I uninstalled Laravel Telescope, and it is now working as it was before. I hope this can be helpful to anyone.